# OS X Laravel Installation fail on XAMPP using Composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have installed composer as Laravel docs instruct. I then ran the following command to instal Laravel: `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist`

I get the following:

```
    The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.4)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.4)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel/zipball/901a45fd96a7479e77f63ea5f8d1147a2766cafa" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.4)
    Cloning 901a45fd96a7479e77f63ea5f8d1147a2766cafa

Created project in your-project-name
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.1)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Failed to download vlucas/phpdotenv from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/vlucas/phpdotenv/zipball/0cac554ce06277e33ddf9f0b7ade4b8bbf2af3fa" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.1)
    Cloning 0cac554ce06277e33ddf9f0b7ade4b8bbf2af3fa

  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.7.3)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Failed to download symfony/var-dumper from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/var-dumper/zipball/e8903ebba5eb019f5886ffce739ea9e3b7519579" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.7.3)
    Cloning e8903ebba5eb019f5886ffce739ea9e3b7519579

  - Installing symfony/translation (v2.7.3)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Failed to download symfony/translation from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/Translation/zipball/c8dc34cc936152c609cdd722af317e4239d10dd6" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/translation (v2.7.3)
    Cloning c8dc34cc936152c609cdd722af317e4239d10dd6

  - Installing symfony/routing (v2.7.3)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Failed to download symfony/routing from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/Routing/zipball/ea9134f277162b02e5f80ac058b75a77637b0d26" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/routing (v2.7.3)
    Cloning ea9134f277162b02e5f80ac058b75a77637b0d26
```

So first it says that it failed to do blah but then it says installing, cloning etc. I check the folder `your-project-name` and it has like 190MB of stuff. So did it work or not? If not how can I fix this issue?

I am running OS X Mavericks and PHP 5.6+

I looked at other answers but none seem to work for my system.

Answer (score 1):

I install openssl via homebrew:

```
brew install openssl
```

This installs the openssl certificates to /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem, so we can now use the new PHP 5.6 INI setting openssl.cafile to tell PHP where to find the certificates:

Adding

```
openssl.cafile=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
```

Comment: Worked on El Capitan as well, packagist suddenly threw an error on composer update and had to perform these steps. I suspect a background Apple update installed something with its own SSL that affected this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel c:/xampp/htdocs/laravel
```

-Here the path is(c:/xampp/htdocs/laravel) so change it to yours.

-If not work,than you have to reinstall ca-cert package and it will
 fixed the problem!

Comment: and how do i install these certs?

Comment: I install openssl via homebrew:

    brew install openssl

This installs the openssl certificates to /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem, so we can now use the new PHP 5.6 INI setting openssl.cafile to tell PHP where to find the certificates:

Adding

openssl.cafile=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem